# Site stuck on working on it - SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server

Recently created a new SharePoint 2016 farm using MinRole for application and WFEwithDC  on dedicated boxes, all went well. I create two web applications for content and MySites.

http://portal
http://mysite

I made host entry 127.0.0.1 for both URLS on WFE and host file entry on App Server with IP of WFE to point everything to WFE from both boxes.

Question is when I try to access the site from WFE or App server, home page get stuck at “Working on it” for hours and never loads . I try to go to settings page by entering the URL manually and I was able to go to the page. Any idea why it is stuck at working on it ? 
So after I change the host file entries on app server to 127.0.0.1 to point the URL to the app server itself ( instead of WFE)  and site came up fine.
I can delete and recreate those 2 web apps but would like to know what is going on here , is this something to do with MinRole ?

Please share your thoughts comments . Thanks

Comment: is loop back check disabled on server? what is the behavior from client machine not from server?

Comment: Thanks for replying , yes , Loopback check is disabled. I am getting the same behavior from the client machine as well. interesting part is if I point the site to the App Server using host files it works. it seems like an issue at the server level but I can be wrong too.

Comment: Did u check uls logs? Is ur Upa is running and connected to web application? Also root site collections are created?

Comment: UPA is running . connected to web application as well.  To make sure I just disconnect and reconnect . Root site collection are created, which can be accessed if I point the sit to the server running with MinRole =Application.

Comment: Logs : I see ULS logs folder are empty on Serer with WFE role . I see logs are available in the Application server. it seems like WFE is not doing any thing and so no logs in the ULS log folder , its creating folder after 30 min with nothing in it.

Comment: I can see logs related to caching but DC is running on the WFE , I check the permissions mentioned at  the link below but same results. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brian_farnhill/2014/06/24/exception-microsoft-applicationserver-caching-datacacheexception-errorcodeerrca0017substatuses0006/

Comment: let me know if I can provide any more information it seem WFE is not doing any thing but I am surprise how site works fine if I point to the App server.@WaqasSarwarMVP

Comment: from central admin, system settings > Mange server in this farm...can you see both servers with correct role( which u configured)?

Comment: I can see both servers in addition to the third one which is Search Role. Complaint column shows Yes and confirm they are all compliant. I wish I can upload images here too but not sure if  its possible.

Comment: can you see the Web applications on the WFE server? check from IIS? also can u access site from server name and port number

Comment: I can see both web application in IIS , ( IIS site ) on WFE and App Server. I create a new web application with server name ( WFE ) and root level site collection. Same issue with that too . I can access site if I change host file  and resolve it to the Application server. but when I resolve it to WFE where it is suppose to be it get stuck at leading.

Comment: Any firewall or antivirus on server? Have reboot the server? Check the event log for more clue...also try to clear configure cache

Comment: I just reset the config cache on all servers , every thing is back up and i can see all servers from central administration. but the issue is still there . i can check settings page but when i go to home page it is stuck at Working on it.

Comment: As mentioned earlier no logs were logged at WFE , i notice account service is running under was not member of "Performance Log Users" . after adding him in to the group logs are being logged on WFE but issue with "Working on it" when access site is still there .

Comment: Part of issue is resolved by adding " Network Service" account in to "WSS_WPG" group. Took my so long but after adding I can access content web app now from WFE with 127.0.0.1and from client as well. I am still not able to access mysite , I am getting the same reponse from my site "working on it " so it might be an other missing permissions on some where. Thanks Waqas for all this help , any idea where mysite can be missing information , I have check every where with in SharePoint like UPSA , app pool etc ?

Comment: Check app pool account of the mysite...should be in iuser group on server also add into DB owner role of all upa dba(profile, sync, social)...

Comment: App Pool account is member of IIS_IUSRS. I notice app pool account was not DBOwner on 4 databases, made him DBO. message " working on it " is still spinning and taking to my site.

Comment: Another update, after I made app pool DB owner for 4 dbs you mentioned. i just reboot the sql server now and I can access MySite now. Thanks for all your help in this case. I am still curious why this implementation was so messed up with permissions, I never had these issues b4, used autospinstaller this time btw. Next question is how to mark some of these comments as answer as they were very helpful to point me in the right direction.

Comment: i am happy to see that your issue is resolved. i am not big fan of autospinstaller but people love it. may be during the installation / configuration something happen and installer miss some steps....You cant mark them as answer but let me add those into the answer section then you can mark it as answer

Comment: I agree with what you said about script, and this is the only reason I used this time ppl were talking so much about it. I have way more control and visibility when doing every thing with GUI or with individual power shell. Thanks again .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are many reasons for this behavior, i would check following things.

- check the ULS logs and Event Logs...But you said ULS logs empty then check WSS WPG admin account has read and write permission on the Log directory.
- Check the Status of the servers in the Central admin, if it is compliance with MinRole.
- Make Sure web Application provisioned on the WFE.
- No AntiVirus or Firewall Blocking on the server
- Loop Back Check is disabled
- UPA is provisioned and connected to the web application.
- App Pool account should have permission on the UPA DBs.